# Can't Filter JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, xamarin, .net-core

I'm trying to Filter the `id` of Connections by `name` e.g. return the `id` of connection, where the `name` is Equal to *12345678*.

I'm able to get all of records and also the values of `id` & `name` as well.

But, I Just want to Filer it e.g. How could I only get the record's `id`, where the `name` is equal to *12345678*? I wrote the code below (I know it's stupid) and it's returning the all records.

**CODE**

```
public class Alias
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Connections
{
    public Alias alias { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Connections> connections { get; set; }
} 

    HttpClient hTTPClient = new HttpClient();

    UserID = "12345678";

    Uri getConnections = new Uri(string.Format("http://0.0.0.0:0000/getConnections"));
    HttpResponseMessage restponseConnections = await hTTPClient.GetAsync(getConnections);
    string contentConnections = await restponseConnections.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contentConnections);

    foreach (Connections i in obj.connections)
    {
        if(!(i.alias.name == UserID))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.id);
        }
    }
```

**JSON**

```
    {
        "success": true,
        "connections": [
            {
                "typeName": "AF.ConnectionRecord"
                "alias": {
                    "name": "12345678",
                    "imageUrl": null
                },
                "endpoint": {
                    "did": null,
                    "verkey": [
                        "6KZYwhxzxWcrZnQravocia2XHyoK9V8pBVT7nBdAd5JX"
                    ],
                    "uri": "http://0.0.0.0:0000"
                },
                "state": 2,
                "id": "d0e4ccbf-5e2a-47bb-a218-78ea93a6066b",
                "createdAtUtc": "2020-10-27T08:01:43.0724247",
                "updatedAtUtc": "2020-10-27T08:01:45.7475196"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: API is Yours? Better approach is filter at API side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use LINQ

```
using System.Linq;
...
var list = obj.connections.Where(c => c.alias.name == "xyz").ToList();
```

Comment: should be `obj`

Comment: for `obj.Connections.Where()` it says *doesn't contain definition for `Connections`*

Comment: use obj.connections

Comment: for `obj.connections.Where()` it says *Omitting the type argument is not allowed in the current context* & 
*Unexpected use of an ubound generic*

Comment: @crankedrelic I also used that

Comment: use .ToList()  instead of .ToList<>()

Comment: it compiled, but I'm not getting anything `var list = obj.connections.Where(c => c.alias.name == "xyz").ToList();`
`Console.WriteLine(list);`

Comment: I used this inside and outside of foreach loop, no luck :)

Comment: do you actually have any data that has `name = "xyz"`?

Comment: oh sorry, but now I replace xyz with `UserID` which had the value of 62434033 ... I used it inside and outside look, but no luck again :)

Comment: first, take a moment to understand what this code does. Search for linq. Another problem with your code may be the '==' operator. Try string.Equals.

Comment: have you checked that your json is being deserialized correctly?

Comment: the "name" field contains a **user id**?

Comment: yes.. when I print list on console, I get this `System.Collections.Generic.List1[Mobile.App.ViewModels.FormViewModel+Connections]`

Comment: there is nothing in your json that contains a string "62434033"

Comment: because the name I use there is dummy... I have a list of all the connections, I'm getting from API

Comment: this will list all the "name" values in your data - `foreach (Connections i in obj.connections) Console.WriteLine(i.alias.name);`

Comment: yes, I've already tried this.. `Console.WriteLine(i.alias.name);` `Console.WriteLine(i.id);`... and i'm getting the id and name.. it's working fine

Comment: solved it, `foreach (Connections i in obj.connections.Where(c => c.alias.name == UserID)){}`...

Comment: and yes, which approach will u choose? filtering on foreach or outside (ur's approach)... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case assuming you want to get 1 record, I'd suggest you use LINQ

```
using System.Linq;

//Rest of your code
var recId = obj.connections.Where(c => c.alias.name == "1234567").FirstOrDefault();
```